# Adding nodes to XML with a form

Tags: javascript, xml, forms, list, xslt

I've created a list using XML and have embedded an XSL stylesheet in it. Now I want to know, because this is a list of movies that constantly grows, is there a way to create a form that will add child and grandchild nodes to the list.

I'm thinking there might be some javascript involved, but I have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to scripting.

Answer (score 0):

If the intension is to write new entries into this xml file you need to look at some form of serverside scripting. Javascript can not write to files.

PHP is probably the easiest to understand, start by buying a book that explains the basics with a few examples, it's not that hard to grasp, and a form and a simple function for writing to files shouldn't take you to long to figure out.

If you have no interest in that sort of thing, hire someone to do the job for you, it will probably only take a few hours for someone who knows what they are doing to get a complete system up and running for you, and unless you really would like to learn a serverside language that is probably the best option.

Comment: So there's no way to do it client-side? At all? I mean, if there isn't, it's no big deal. I just wanted to make life a little easier. But if there's no possible way to do it client-side, I guess I'll just have to live with that. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Well, no! javascript is running on the users computer in the browser, and does not have access to the files on your server, even with ajax it doesn't really have access to files, as a serverside language does that part.

Comment: All I really want is to be able to craft a form that, when submitted, would be able to add nodes to the xml tree and have it all contained in one file.

Comment: Yes, and it's actually not that hard to do, but it will require a serverside script to receive the form and append the data to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it all on the client side, you can try [HTML5 client-side storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage). This means the data will be persistent only for the user that enters the data (and only for the browser used to enter it, and only on the computer that was used).

If you want the movies to be accessible to multiple people, or from multiple computers, you need to use server-side storage.

FYI, HTML5 storage is not yet very well standardized across browsers.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you for telling me about this. I had no idea. Do you know how I could create some sort of form that will add nodes to the page and have it locally stored?

Comment: @SamuelPearseWalters: the question is very broad... I would put a javascript function call in the form's `action` attribute, and the function would use jQuery to add nodes to the page. For local storage, see the link in my answer, which describes various offline technologies, with some of their pros and cons, browser support, and links to examples.

Comment: @SamuelPearseWalters: as you get into it and come up with more specific questions, you can post them on SO, e.g. "how do I add a node to the page in jQuery?" or "how do I store an XML document using local storage?" These may be answered already.